# SFTP linux server with windows AD file server backend

Tags: active-directory, reverse-proxy, sftp, cifs

I need to configure an sftp server (sftp-server) to give access to a Windows shared folder using Windows AD authentication (Freeipa is already configured in sftp-server) and permissions configured on the Windows server (win-fs).
Now you are working by mounting the shared folder over cifs, but only for one user.
sftab line:

```
 \\win-fs\shared_folder /local_mount cifs credentials =/root/creds-smb-ad_user,_netdev,uid=local_user,gid=users 0 0
```

The requirement now is to authenticate more than one user and manage permissions through Windows AD.
Googling I found this [LINK](https://www.jscape.com/blog/mapping-ftp-ftps-sftp-server-directories-to-samba-shares) which shows how to configure an sftp proxy pointing to a Windows share.
This is a payment solution.
Can anyone tell me how can I do this with the open source options?

If this question has already been answered anywhere, thank you for pasting the link.

So thanks for everything.